# arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray adding fake objects when second array is empty?

Tags: objective-c

I am calling it like:

> NSMutableArray* wanted_items = (NSMutableArray*)[self.has_items arrayByAddingObject:self.near_items];

When self.near_items is empty, and self.has_items has one element, I end up with wanted_items having two elements in it, the first being from has_items and the second being some weird crazy empty THING that is apparently not nil or NSNULL.

What is going on here? Am I doing it wrong?

Edit:

If I do it backwards (add has_items to near_items) I correctly get an array with a single element...and that element is the weird blank thing.

when I just try to print it out, I get:

> (
>       (null)
>   )

When i try to print out the original order I get:

> *nil description*

(for the correct one) and

> ( )

for the incorrect one (no (null) inside)

Is this method just not intended to be used with initialized but empty arrays?

Edit:

Doing

```
   NSMutableArray* wanted_items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [wanted_items addObjectsFromArray:self.has_items];
    [wanted_items addObjectsFromArray:self.near_items];
```

gets me exactly what i wanted (both arrays squished together, even if one or both is nil).

Was I just completely wrong on what the other array does? Why was it adding the empty array as an element? I was expecting it to be like concatenation...

Comment: Would that crazy thing be an empty array? what else were you expecting to happen?

Comment: Why don't you go play around a bit with the `description` method of objects? Ya know, the message `NSLog()` sends an object when it's printed using `%@`. According to that, `(null)` is `NULL` or `nil` or `Nil`, `<null>` is `NSNull`, `()` is an empty array, and `( (null) )` is an array containing `nil`, which is is impossible since `NSArray` **cannot contain** `nil`.

Comment: I was expecting [1,2,3] + [] to be [1,2,3], or [1,2,3] + [4] to be [1,2,3,4].  Is this for having arrays of arrays then?

Comment: @Jenny You are not doing [1,2,3]+[], you are doing [1,2,3]+[ [] ]. The first piece of code is calling `arrayByAddingObject` instead of `arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray`. It is adding array as an object because that's exactly what you've written.

Comment: ah yeah, that'll do it. thanks very much!  If you make that an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is calling `arrayByAddingObject:` instead of `arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:`, and that is the reason why you have the argument array appended as element, instead of getting concatenated arrays.